# loss function values converge differently with each new model launch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, loss

I build a neural network model with regression for predict an insurance prime. My loss function decrease until near the zero, but loss function values ​​converge differently with each new model launch.

```
...
Epoch: 30/30 Train Loss: 0.1665 
Epoch: 30/30 Validation Loss: 1.2689

...
Epoch: 30/30 Train Loss: 4.6166 
Epoch: 30/30 Validation Loss: 4.4621 

...
Epoch: 30/30 Train Loss: 1.3190 
Epoch: 30/30 Validation Loss: 1.3700
```

Is correct that each time the loss converge with different values? The predict value following the loss output

The code of model:

```
#################
#TRAIN E TEST SET
#################
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_data, test_data = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.25)

train_id=train_data["ID"]
test_id=test_data["ID"]

##################
#TESNORFLOW MODEL
##################

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


############################
#Split training in validation
############################

def split_valid_test_data(data, fraction=(1 - 0.8)):
    data_y=train_data.as_matrix(columns=[train_data.columns[8]])
    data_x = data.drop(["Prime"], axis=1)
    train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = train_test_split(data_x, data_y, test_size=fraction)
    return train_x.values, train_y, valid_x, valid_y

train_x, train_y, valid_x, valid_y = split_valid_test_data(train_data)

print("train_x:{}".format(train_x.shape))
print("train_y:{}".format(train_y.shape))
print("train_y content:{}".format(train_y[:3]))

print("valid_x:{}".format(valid_x.shape))
print("valid_y:{}".format(valid_y.shape))


##########
#Parameters
##########
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 30
batch_size =100
display_step = 1
total_len = train_x.shape[0]
# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 16# 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 14 # 2nd layer number of features
n_hidden_3 = 12
n_hidden_4 = 10
n_input = train_x.shape[1]
n_classes = 1

###############
#tf Graph input
###############

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, train_x.shape[1]])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None,n_classes])

#################
#Model
#################

def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(layer_3)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.relu(layer_4)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

##################################
#weight & bias
##################################
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0,0.1, dtype=tf.float32)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0,0.1,dtype=tf.float32)),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3], 0,0.1,dtype=tf.float32)),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4], 0,0.1,dtype=tf.float32)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_classes], 0, 0.1,dtype=tf.float32))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0,0.1,dtype=tf.float32)),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0,0.1,dtype=tf.float32)),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3], 0,0.1,dtype=tf.float32)),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4], 0,0.1,dtype=tf.float32)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes], 0, 0.1,dtype=tf.float32))
}

pred= multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

##############################################
#  loss e optimizer
###############################################

###########
#MSE
###########

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))

########
#batch
########

def get_batch(data_x,data_y,batch_size):  
    batch_n=len(data_x)//batch_size
    for i in range(batch_n):
        batch_x=data_x[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        batch_y=data_y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        yield batch_x,batch_y

train_collect = 50
train_print=train_collect*2


x_collect = []
train_loss_collect = []
train_acc_collect = []
valid_loss_collect = []
valid_acc_collect = []

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    iteration=0
    for e in range(training_epochs) :
        for batch_x,batch_y in get_batch(train_x,train_y,batch_size):
            iteration+=1
            feed = {x: train_x,
                    y: train_y
                   }
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:train_x, y: train_y})
            train_loss, train_acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict=feed)  #_, optimizer
            prediction_train = sess.run([pred], feed_dict=feed)
            if iteration % train_collect == 0:
                x_collect.append(e)
                train_loss_collect.append(train_loss)
                train_acc_collect.append(train_acc)
                if iteration % train_print==0:
                     print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e + 1, training_epochs),
                      "Train Loss: {:.4f}".format(train_loss),
                      "Train Acc: {:.4f}".format(train_acc))       
                feed = {x: valid_x,
                        y: valid_y
                       }
                val_loss, val_acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
                valid_loss_collect.append(val_loss)
                valid_acc_collect.append(val_acc) 
                if iteration % train_print==0:
                    print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(e + 1,training_epochs),
                      "Validation Loss: {:.4f}".format(val_loss),
                      "Validation Acc: {:.4f}".format(val_acc))
    saver.save(sess, "./prova_habitas.ckpt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, neural networks are very sensitive to initialisation.

Try reducing the initialised values of your variables, for example

```
'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], 0,0.1, dtype=tf.float32) * 0.001)
```

Comment: I tried to change learning rate (0.5, 0.1, 0.01 and 0.001) --> the best is last one. With 3 hidden layer then 2 the loss function decrease more quick.  I chenged mean and sd in weight and bias but the best is what you see in the code. Other moltiplication a value to weight and bias there are other initialised? I don't understand if is correct or not that the loss function decrease with different value

Comment: The convergence will always be a little bit different. You will never get 2 exactly the same values for the loss function because the initialisation and some other bits are random. 
As long as you always converge to a similar value (let's say your loss always converges to 0.01), then your training is finished (whether or not your model can perform better is a different question).

Comment: All right, I know that the model doesn't  return always the same loss value. But my model sometimes return loss values about 4 and other times return value about 0.16. There is a big different between 4 and 0.16, for this motive iask if is correct. Probabily I have to set better the hyperparameters. Do you know other methods to initialise the hyperparameters?